# My script can't recognise names inside the username file

Tags: python, file, path

*It can see the file, if i change the name on the path slightly run seizes to function but eithr way it can't read the words in the file despite being able to before while I was writing the program. And now suddenly it doesn't work, the file location is the same and all.*

P.S. I have no idea how to specify code on overflow

```
filen = 'C:\Users\fabby\Documents\Extra Things I Might Need\Port Folio Stuff\Python\usernames'
usern = open(filen, 'r')
userr = input("Enter your Username: ")
ass = input("Enter your Password: ")


def func():
    user = input("Enter new Username: ")
    passs = input("Enter new Password: ")
    passs1 = input("Confirm password: ")

    if passs != passs1:
        print("Passwords do not match!")
    else:
        if len(passs) <= 6:
            print("Your password is too short, restart:")

        elif user in usern:
            print("This username already exists")

        else:
            usern = open(filen, "a")
            usern.write(user+", "+passs+"\n")
            print("Success!")

while True:
    if userr not in usern:
        again = input("This username does not exist, would you like to try again? ")
        if again == ("No"):
            func()
        elif again == ("no"):
            func()
        elif again == ("Yes"):
            print("Try again:")
            userr = input("Enter your Username: ")
            ass = input("Enter your Password: ")
        elif again == ("yes"):
            print("Try again:")
            userr = input("Enter your Username: ")
            ass = input("Enter your Password: ")
        elif userr in usern:
            print("Good, you have entered the zone")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I have full understand your means, but as your code, I have some suggestions:

1. close file if you open it
2. use f.readline() and str.split() to parse username and passwd and store in array, so you can use in to check, if the file is not to large.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).